# How does one extract the original head of an expression?

Tags: functions, expression-manipulation, core-language

The expression `Head[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]` returns `Graphics`. Might it be possible to extract the original head of an expression without evaluation transforming it into something else?

My ultimate objective is to be able to pass any expression say, `f[x]` as an argument `arg` to another function `g[arg]` and then within `g` do something like this:

`IN:: f[x]:= x; g[arg] := Module[{head}, **Some other stuff**; head = Head@arg; head]; g[f@x]`

`OUT:: f`

However, doing:

`IN::  g[arg] := Module[{head}, **Some other stuff**; head = Head@arg; head]; g[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]]`

I get:

`OUT:: Graphics`

This also happens when setting the Attributes of `g` to `HoldFirst` etc.

Comment: That's because arg gets evaluated before being passed to `Head`. Try using [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html): `Head@Unevaluated@arg`

Comment: It works! So simple too, thanks a lot.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Working with unevaluated expressions](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/).

Answer (score 4):

In a practical scenario, you may be storing your expression in a variable.  To be able to do so, it must be held unevaluated.

```
expr = Hold[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]
(* Hold[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]] *)
```

Then you can simply use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).

```
expr[[1, 0]]
(* Plot *)
```

[`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html) will be useful (only) when the expression is inserted literally into `Unevaluated`.

```
Head@Unevaluated@Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]
(* Plot *)

SetAttributes[fun, HoldAll]
fun[expr_] := Head@Unevaluated[expr]

fun[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]
(* Plot *)
```

This does not work:

```
expr := Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]

Head@Unevaluated[expr]
(* Symbol *)
```

Recommended reading:

- [Working With Unevaluated Expressions](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/377/)

Comment: This is very useful! I have been going with `Unevaluated` for explicitly passing expressions to functions with Hold attributes, and then Part for modifying those expressions within functions. The reference is also very good. Thanks.